# When running Gradle task with "gradlew", It fails

Tags: android, gradle, build-tools

I have a really weird problem and could not get it for days.If I running this Gradle command with gradlew wrapper it fails as follows:

```
$ ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest

javax.annotation.processing does not exist
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
                                  ^
error: cannot find symbol
@Generated(
 ^
symbol: class Generated
```

However, If I run the clean command and then run `testDebugUnitTest` task again from Gradle panel it will be completed successfully as you see in the pics.

What is the difference between using `.gradlew` to running tasks and using Gradle panel. Actually Gradle view uses internally this gradlew. [image: running <code>testDebugUnitTest</code> from Gradle View]

[image]

Comment: Which Gradle version? What happens if you run `./gradlew clean testDebugUnitTest` from the command line?

Comment: Gradle version: 5.4  and tried `./gradlew clean testDebugUnitTest` from the command line, the same exception happened. Its so weird that when I  run this command from Gradle panel, it works.

Comment: When you run the build from the command line, which Java version is used? Which Java version is used in IDEA?